# Simplifying Boolean Expression with Multiple Parameters

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can someone help me simplify tis boolean expression, I have been trying all morning with no luck. It has multiple parameters and I have no idea if I have to use De Morgan and when. The expression is:

ABC + DE + AF +ABDF + A'F

All i come up with is is this: AB(C+DF)+DE+F but then I have to design a circuit with logical gates that accept only two parameters, so I'm lost.

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  ABC + DE + AF + A'F + ABDF
  &= 
  ABC + DE +(A+A')F + ABDF \\
  &= 
  ABC + DE + (1)F + ABDF \\
  &= 
  ABC + DE + F + ABDF \\
  &=
  ABC + DE + (1 + ABD)F \\
  &=
  ABC + DE+ F
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer but im afraid you did a mistake right there, its 
A'F not AF'.

Comment: I have edited u can check now

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick responses, the problem is that the the resulting circuit has an AND gate with three parameters, and I am restricted to logical gates with only 2 parameters(that's what the excercise demands unfortunately)

Comment: If the answer is useful you could upvote it and mark it as correct so that others know it was useful.